# Android picker/list similar to iOS date picker

Tags: android, picker

I'd like to implement an ios style picker on Android with multiple columns, such as this one:

[image]

Yes, I know that Android has a slightly different platform default for this kind of UI, but I really like the IOS style that shows the different options above and below and lets you easily drag up and down.

I'm already aware of this [DateSlider](https://github.com/bendemboski/DateSlider) project, but it's specific for dates, and I want to use it for custom lists. And also it uses horizontal scrolling rather than vertical.

Thanks!

Comment: its suggested not to use the slider as its not the design principle according to Android. just an advice

Comment: Yes, I have taken that design principle into account. It's a conscious decision :-)

Comment: check out this library for implementation https://arkapp.medium.com/ios-date-time-picker-for-android-93af45fdfaf0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was looking for something like that, until I found [this widget](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/). This is how it looks like:

[image] [image]

Although I still didn't find a way to use it in my app ! Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: that looks great, will check it out

Comment: Yes it does look great. however, I'm still struggling trying to use it in my app :(

Comment: above provided link is not available at GitHub any one can use following this link to get download code easy   https://github.com/erpragatisingh/android-wheel/

Comment: Works Awesome. Thank you. Source code also available guys. Check it.

Answer (score 3):

I reworked widget mentioned my iturki. Have a look:

[image]

Code on [github](https://github.com/ayushhgoyal/AyushWheel/).

Comment: can you share your code for the layout and activity

Comment: I got stuck in same problem before. So i made custom solution for that : https://arkapp.medium.com/ios-date-time-picker-for-android-93af45fdfaf0

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing built into Android is the [Time Picker](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-timepicker.html). Its not as fancy as its iOS counterpart, but gets the job done.

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with the time picker ... but I'm looking for specifically the ios style. I understand it doesn't come in the SDK by default, but I have seen existing android apps that are using it, so I'm hoping someone has written an open source sample :-)

Comment: Got ya. Yeah it would be nice as the Android widget is pretty ugly.

Comment: Check this library https://github.com/blessedCode07/iOS-date-time-picker

Answer (score 0):

An alternative DatePicker for Android 
http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/